# Worklight LTPA Authentication with WebSphere

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am using worklight 6.1 and WebSphere 8

I am getting following error

**[ERROR ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'WASLTPAModule' failed. SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html. [project Streebo] SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html [ERROR ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule WASLTPAModule, User Identity Not available. [project Streebo] [project Streebo] [WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html**

Here are the things what I did

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
<testAppAuthenticity/> 
<testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
<testUser realm="WASLTPARealm" />
</mobileSecurityTest>


<!-- For websphere -->
<realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule"><className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
<parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
<parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
</realm>


<!-- For websphere -->
<loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
<className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

**Adapter Entry**

```
WASAuth.xml
<procedure name="getAuth" securityTest="mobileTests"/>

WASAuth-impl.js
function getAuth() {
return {'key1':'authh'};
}
```

**Challenge Handler**

```
var challengeHandler;
challengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler('WASLTPARealm');
```

**initOptions.js**

```
connectOnStartup : false,
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
WL.Client.connect({
    onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
    onFailure: onConnectFailure
});
```

and its going in onSuccess

```
function onConnectSuccess() {
alert('on connect success in wlCommonInit() in main.js');

var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'WASAuth',
    procedure : 'getAuth',
    parameters : []
};

var options = {
    onSuccess : function(res) {
        alert('procedure getAuth success with res: '+res);          
    },
    onFailure : function() {
        alert('procedure getAuth Failures');
    }
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

};

So its coming in success function and when It calls adapter and following error comes

**[ERROR   ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'WASLTPAModule' failed. SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html. [project Streebo]
SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule WASLTPAModule, User Identity Not available. [project Streebo] [project Streebo]
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /login.html**

And I already have login.html and loginError.html in root folder of my war and also have login.html in conf

Please guide me to resolve this issue

Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Please verify you have named the files login.html and loginError.html exactly. Please also verify you have placed these in the root of the war file that you have deployed to your server. You can expand the war file you have deployed to double check. Also make sure your login.html file has valid structure such as the example provided:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="j_security_check">
      <input type="text"
             id="j_username"
             name="j_username"
             placeholder="User name" />
      <input type="password"
             id="j_password"
             name="j_password"
             placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Log In" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As well as the structure of your loginError.html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    An error occurred while trying to log in.
  </body>
</html>
```

For more detailed instructions and troubleshooting please look at the following:

**LTPA Training Module:**
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_06_WebSphere_LTPA_based_authentication.pdf

**LTPA Infocenter Instructions**
https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_WL_LTPA_realm.html

Comment: After changing login.html as above, at one point I saw html in logcat but again it started giving me same error, Any Idea ? I looked at articles you suggested, looks like same thing I implemented, Now I am stuck and really dont know where to proceed

Comment: Hello, how to place html files in the root of war file? do I need to do it manually or there is way to have it in the right place when Eclipse generate my war file?

Answer (score 0):

For MobileFirst Platform v6.3

\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\apps

Find the app that you are trying to test ltpa with.

Assuming the project name is FormBasedAuth.  Then the corresponding war file is FormBasedAuth.war

Using WinRAR to open it.

Go to your studio workbench, in your project > expand server > expand conf > copy the login.html into the FormBasedAuth.war that is already opened in WinRAR

you could also create a loginError.html and put that into the FormBaseAuth.war

Make sure that you place FormBaseAuth.war back to \MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\apps

Now in the studio, server view > Stop the test server.  Wait for it to stop.
Start the test server again.

Now when you test, this error will be gone.

Similar procedure for the standalone server, just your war file might be different.